# Accessing args without passing it and avoiding a global variable

Tags: c, argv

```c
void k() {
   I need argv here
}
void j() { k(); }
void h() { j(); }
void g() { h(); }
void f() { g(); }
void e() { f(); }
void d() { e(); }
void c() { d(); }
void b() { c(); }
void a() { b(); }
int main(int argc, char **argv) { a(); }
```

How to access command line args (either as a vector or a plain string) in my deeply accessed function `k`? I do not want to use a global variable (that's what I do now actually and want to avoid). Also passing it to every fuction is not a good option. Actually passing it as an argument to all functions from `a` to `k` is not even possible because some functions are defined by libraries and I cannot change their headings/code. Maybe there is ANSI C standard way for doing that?

Comment: Obviously since it is a parameter to the function `main()`, you will need to pass it from main to `K()`. Your other option is to use a global pointer -- which you want to avoid. Pass it as a parameter. You can pass `argv` as `char **` or `argv[x]` as `char *`, so you have two options depending on your library functions.

Comment: You could assign it to a `static` variable somewhere and have a global function which returns it - not sure how that's really better than a global variable though.  What's so bad about the global variable?  Some people are reflexively opposed to them, but there are places where they make sense and this is one.  C isn't one of those languages that gives you dozens of reasonable choices as to how to do something.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Generally, the OS kernel passes command-line arguments from the parent process to the child process by putting them in a known location in the address space of the child process.  The code in the child process that runs before `main()` is called then finds the arguments, counts them to set `argc`, and then calls `main()` with the arguments. And if the pre-`main()` code can find the arguments, so can your code... (Note that implementations of argument passing are simple and stable, too) What OS are you running on?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you can't pass it as function argument, you need some kind of static storage, e.g. a global variable.

To avoid making it a global variable, you can put it into a function so that the variable is local to that function. Like

```
char** get_argv(char** p)
{
    static char** s_argv = NULL;
    if (s_argv == NULL) s_argv = p; // Will set the static variable the first
                                    // time this function is called
                                    // After that it's "read only"
    return s_argv;
}

void b()
{
    char** argv = get_argv(NULL);      // This will read the static variable
    if (argv) printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
}

void a() { b(); }

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    get_argv(argv);  // This will set the static variable inside the function get_argv
    a(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of (without using a global variable) is passing argv all the way down:

```
void k(char **argv) {
   I need argv here
}
void j(char **argv) { k(argv); }
void h(char **argv) { j(argv); }
void g(char **argv) { h(argv); }
void f(char **argv) { g(argv); }
void e(char **argv) { f(argv); }
void d(char **argv) { e(argv); }
void c(char **argv) { d(argv); }
void b(char **argv) { c(argv); }
void a(char **argv) { b(argv); }
int main(int argc, char **argv) { a(argv); }
```

Comment: OP explcit states that: " Actually passing it as an argument to all functions from a to k is not even possible  because some functions are defined by libraries and I cannot change their headings/code." so this doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux (and Solaris 11.4) you can read `/proc/self/cmdline` (error checking and proper header include directives omitted to shorten the example and eliminate any scroll bar for readability):

```
char **getArgv()
{
    int fd = open( "/proc/self/cmdline", O_RDONLY );
#ifdef sun
    struct stat sb;
    fstat( fd, &sb );
    size_t bytes = sb.st_size;
#else
    size_t bytes = getProcFileSize( fd );
#endif
    char *content = malloc( bytes );
    read( fd, content, bytes );
    close( fd );

    // count '\0' characters in file for number of args
    int argCount = 0;
    for ( int ii = 0; ii < bytesRead; ii++ )
    {
        if ( !content[ ii ] ) argCount++;
    }
    // add 1 for terminating NULL
    char **argv = calloc( argCount + 1, sizeof( *argv ) );

    // point argv values into content
    for ( int offset = 0, int arg = 0; arg < argCount; arg++ )
    {
        argv[ arg ] = &( content[ offset ] );
        offset += strlen( argv[ arg ] ) + 1;
    }

    return( argv );
}
```

To get the size of a file such as `cmdline` in `/proc/` on Linux, since `[f|l]stat()` returns zero:

```
size_t getProcFileSize( int fd )
{
    char buffer[ 1024 ];

    lseek( fd, 0, SEEK_SET );
    size_t total = 0;
    for ( ;; )
    {
        ssize_t bytesRead = read( fd, buffer, sizeof( buffer ) );
        if ( bytesRead <= 0 )
        {
            break;
        }
        total += bytesRead;
    }

    lseek( fd, 0, SEEK_SET );
    return( total );
}
```

To free:

```
void freeArgv( char **argv )
{
    // *argv (or argv[ 0 ]) points to
    // the content block allocated in getArgv()
    free( *argv );
    free( argv );
}
```

Note - I'm not sure which version of Solaris 11 was the first with a Linux-style `cmdline` file in `/proc/[PID]`.  It does exist in 11.4, and I'm pretty sure it did not exist in 11.0.